# What’s the meaning of “or near enough as makes no matter”

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

I’ve seen people hinted that “makes no matter” means “it doesn’t matter”, but the whole phrase still doesn’t make much sense to me.

Here are some of the examples I found.

> Like most of you (I gather), I reread "A Song of Ice and Fire" about
> once per year, or *near enough as makes no matter*.

> “How many is it now?” Bran asked Maester Luwin as Lord Karstark and
> his sons rode through the gates in the outer wall.
>
> “Twelve thousand men, or *near enough as makes no matter*.”

> In fact body rigidity is *near enough as it doesn't matter* to the
> sedan, as is the weight distribution front to rear.

Comment: The version common in British English is "as near enough as makes no difference", which might be clearer. I'm a bit surprised that research didn't suggest that variant.

Comment: The sense is "My estimate is so near to the truth that it doesn't matter if it's slightly inaccurate".

Comment: While Kate is totally correct, the statement is a value judgement made by the speaker. They could be totally justified in this assessment, have miscalculated woefully, or even be being deceptive.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What has the judgement of the speaker to do with the meaning? The reliability of the speaker's judgement is not the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the meanings of *matter* are two that matter:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/matter)
> *matter*:
> {1} the reason for pain or worry
> {2} a situation or subject that is being dealt with or considered

something that *makes no matter* is therefore
{1} something that poses no reason for worry or concern
{2} something that does not create a situation to be considered or dealt with.

In both cases, *something that makes no matter* is trivial, has no significant influence on the things being discussed, so need not be considered further.

"*Or near enough ...*" adds the thought that recognisable features of the "something" are relatively (compared to the main line of thought) small enough to have no significance

Dealing with your examples:

"*about once per year, or near enough as makes no matter*" = about once a year, perhaps a little more, perhaps a little less, but the important thing is that it was read roughly once per year.

"*Twelve thousand men, or near enough as makes no matter*" = roughly twelve (rather than eleven or thirteen, for example) thousand, but the exact value has no influence on the outcome.

"*body rigidity is near enough as it doesn't matter to the sedan*" = the rigidity is similar to and roughly the same as that of a sedan; there are minor differences but they do not detract from the similarity.